# Combine 2 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I need to combine or merge together. I am at a bit of a loss as to how to achieve this.
So the first array looks like this:

```
$arr1 = 
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [round] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [round] => 2
    )
....
```

And the second array looks like this:

```
$arr2 = 
Array (
[round_1] => 21
[round_2] => 32
....
```

And I need the result to end up like this:

```
$result = 
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [round] => 1
        [disp] => 21
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [round] => 2
        [disp] => 32
    )
...... etc etc
```

Any ideas on where to get started for this??
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? A simple foreach loop would do the trick here.

Comment: I figured a foreach loop would be the way to go. I have looked at `array_merge`, `array_merge_recursive`, `array_push`, `array_combine` but can't work them out and which one I would need. A push in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Sure, Look into foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php And then consider this pseudo code: `go through each inner array of $arr1 assign it with the single elements of arr2 to the result array`

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by 'assign it with'?? This is the bit where I am getting lost. A foreach loop is no problem but just not sure how to actually add them together, or 'assign' the single elements as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 1; // Counter 
$result = $arr1; // Copy $arr1 to preserve it. (if necessary) 

foreach ($result as $x){

    $x['disp'] = $arr2['round_' . $i];
    $i ++;
}
```

This will iterate through Array1 setting a value for 'disp' in each sub array. This value will be pulled from Array2 and the round number would be incremented by a basic counter.

You could equally use a standard for loop for this too.

```
$result = $arr1; // Copy $arr1 to preserve it. (if necessary) 

for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){ 
    $result[$i]['disp'] = $arr2['round_' . ($i + 1)];
}
```

Just make sure you do "$i + 1" when calling the value from Array2 because that doesn't seem to be 0 indexed.